# Can I pipe between commands, and run the programs from different directories?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a particular command, that reacts differently depending on the content of the current working directory.
I now wish to pipe this program back to itself, back have the call happen in different directories.

In "pseudo-bash", I want

```
command arg1 | cd /other dir | command arg2
```

I personally use bash, but if it helps to use a different shell, I'm open to suggestions. :)

I realize there is a very easy workaround with a temporary file or named pipe, but I want to know if there's a way to do this in one command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
command arg1 | ( cd /other_dir ; command arg2 )
```

`(…)` executes a command in a subshell. `cd` is a shell builtin command, not a 'real process'. `( cd X ; command )` will start a new sub-shell, cd into X, then run `command`. `command` is running as a process, but in a different directory.

Going forward it's better to have commands that can take a directory as an argument (and if not defined, default to the current working directory). Then you could have the simple solution of `command arg1 | command --dir=/other_dir arg2`

Comment: If you don't mind altering the cwd of your current shell, you don't need to spawn a subshell: `command1 | { cd /other/dir && command2; }` -- note the trailing semi-colon is required within braces.

Comment: @glenn Is there any shell that will actually change directory when executed that way?  Bash runs each command of the pipeline in a subprocess, even if {} is used.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I can't speak to other shells. Good point about bash though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise to separate the subshell commands with `&&` instead of `;` so that if the `cd` fails the `arg2` command doesn't execute in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 3):

How about using a subshell, something like this:

```
command arg1 | (cd /other/dir; command arg2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipes don't work that way. They are simply a way to pass data streams (*not context*) from one command to another. If you need a command in a pipeline to run in a different *context* from the others, you'll just have to change the directory in that [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), as @JoachimPileborg pointed out.

The canonical way to solve this in *nix shells is to instead pass the relevant directory as a parameter to the script. Your command sequence would then be:

```
command arg1 .
command arg2 /other/dir
```